# MySQL trigger to insert join result of two tables into a third

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables, product, promotion, product_promotion and production_promotion_denormalized. In my products table I have:

```
product_id  product_name
    1        Product A
    2        Product B
```

For promotions:

```
promotion_id  promotion_name
    1        Promo A
    2        Promo B
```

My third table is an associative table, when ever a promotion is created on a product, the associative table gets an entry with the product id and promotion id. So there can be multiple products with multiple promotions and for each combination of product and promotion there will be an entry in this table:

```
id   product_id   promotion_id
1        1            1
2        1            2
3        2            2   
4        2            1
```

My fourth table is a denormalized version, what i want to do is write a trigger in mysql to get product id and its details, along with promotion id and its details and insert them in my fourth table:

```
id   product_id   product_name   promotion_id   promotion_name
1        1           Product A        1            Promo A
2        1           Product A        2            Promo B
3        2           Product B        2            Promo B
4        2           Product B        1            Promo A
```

I need to write this trigger for on insert and on update in mysql.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't do this! Create a `view` if you need a "table" with these values. Apart from that, it is actually straight forward, just look at the trigger examples in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). You would have to create 7 triggers: an update and a delete trigger for both product and promotion and an update, insert and delete trigger for product_promotion (although you can do some of it with cascaded foreign keys). Or create one view that joins your three tables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is that a view will not be able to do the job required in the project. The data needs to be persistent in a table for various reasons. Secondly, I don't need triggers for the product and promotion tables as per my understanding(I stand to be corrected).....I only need to create a trigger on the product_promotion table so when ever the data is inserted or updated the denormalized table is updated as well.

I have written a view which joins the product and promotion tables...what I am stuck at is inserting the results into the denormalized tables.

Comment: Honestly, I cannot think of any valid reason to do it that way (maybe apart from a history table, but then you would need another id-column). It might sometimes seem like the easiest or only solution when you start using databases, but it is not (and you will probably actually create a lot of problems with this, normalization is a really really important principle in relational databases). But well, I warned you, and it is your project, so I will write you a trigger (in a comment, not an answer, because I still think it is the wrong approach).

Comment: `create trigger tri_ppd after insert on product_promotion
for each row insert into product_promotion_denormalized (id, product_id, product_name, promotion_id, promotion_name) select new.id, new.product_id, product_name, new.promotion_id, promotion_name from product pd join promotion pm on pm.id = new.promotion_id where pd.id = new.product_id;`. The update trigger works similarly (see "documentation"-link in my first comment, make it `before update`, and use `new.` and `old.` to find the rows to update). If you ever change a name, you will need triggers on `product` and `promotion` too.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare....getting close to the target. But having an small issue. I have modified the example a bit...following is the updated trigger:

`
INSERT INTO campaignplacedenom 
 (`campaign_name`, `placeName`, `campaign_id`, `place_id`) 
SELECT campaign.campaignName as campaignname, place.placeName as placename, campaign.id as campaignID, place.id as placeID 

FROM campaign_place 

INNER JOIN campaign ON campaign_place.campaign_id = campaign.id 
INNER JOIN place ON campaign_place.place_id = place.id
`
It insert the data but adds an extra record.

Comment: @Solarflare:

for example I have 2 campaigns and 2 places, I insert 2 the records in the campaign_place pivot table and the trigger works, but instead of giving me 2 new entries, it creates 3 entries, and if there are older records in the campaign_place table it creates entries again for them.

Comment: Do NOT use `FROM campaign_place`. I left it out intentionally. You have access to (only) the row you are currently inserting with `new.` (and in the update-trigger additionally `old`.) (That's what a trigger is for: it does something with the current row).

Comment: @Solarflare I tried running the original trigger you shared with the example schema that i posted. getting this error:

#1054 - Unknown column 'pd.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Problem Solved! :-)

Comment: @Solarflare....can you help me with what would be the delete statement for this:

`INSERT INTO campaignplacedenom (id, campaign_id, campaignName, place_id, placeName) select new.id, new.campaign_id, campaignName, new.place_id, placeName from campaign pd join place pm on pm.id = new.place_id where pd.id = new.campaign_id`

Comment: Yes, sorry, the column should be `pd.product_id` instead of `pd.id`. The delete-trigger is short since you know the id: `create trigger trd_cpd after delete on campaignplace for each row delete from campaignplacedenom where id = old.id;` And here is the code for a view that gives you the same result as all your triggers combined (if you name the view `campaignplacedenom`): `create view view_cpd as select cp.*, c.campaignName, p.placeName from campaignplace cp join place p on p.id = cp.place_id join campaign c on c.id = cp.campaign_id;` At least give it a try.

Comment: @Solarflare....Awesome....really appreciate your help. Just one last question, incase of update, what should be my trigger? Should I delete first and then insert again?